# EditingDidBegin event is not triggered second time in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an issue while using `EditingDidBegin` event trigger. I have `UITextFiled` I have triggered the while editing so I have to try to show `datePicker`. The first time its able to trigger the event it has shown the `datePicker`. After selecting `datePicker` I have tried one more time to try editing the `textField`. It has triggered that event. So it displayed the keyboard instead of the `datePicker`.

Comment: Please show the code that you have try that will be more helpful to understand what you have try.

Comment: @IBAction func SelectExpireDate(sender: UITextField) {
        textFieldShouldReturn(self.ExpireDate);
        calling_date_picker;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol on your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ...
```

Make sure the view controller is hooked up as the delegate of the UITextField in the storyboard.

Then, implement the textFieldShouldBeginEditing function:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("show date picker")
    return false
}
```

Returning false means that the text field will never start editing, so you can show the date picker instead.

The above code will show the date picker for every tap on every UITextField that delegates to that view controller. If you want finer control than that then you'll need to hook up a referencing outlet and check in textFieldShouldBeginEditing to see if its the right text field. Or you could use tags (ugh).